# Open inbound calls redirects to another Twilio client when hang up

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-twiml

I have two available Twilio `<client>` to receive inbound calls on my website (after caller enters a code) using JS Quickstart and Twilio client PHP library, these calls are recorded and registered on my database.

I've noticed when one `<client>` hangs up an open inbound call , this call goes to the website of the other `<client>` I have have 2 registers on my database instead of one.

This is an example:

```
<?php

//...
//Validating connection status
//$estd is the connection status I get via AJAX

if($estd=="open"){ 
    $call = $twilio->calls($callsid)->update(array("status" => "completed"));
    $calla = $twilio->calls($callsid)->fetch();
    $parentCall = $calla->parentCallSid; //parent call
    $calld = $twilio->calls($parentCall)->update(array("status" => "completed"));
} else if($estd=="pending"){
    $call = $twilio->calls($callsid)->update(array("status" => "completed"));
    $calla = $twilio->calls($callsid)->fetch();
    $parentCall = $calla->parentCallSid; //parent call
    $calld = $twilio->calls($parentCall)->update(array("twiml" => '<Response><Dial timeout="20" record="record-from-answer" recordingStatusCallback="https://mywebsite.com/record.php" recordingStatusCallbackEvent="in-progress completed absent"><Client><Identity>the_other_client</Identity><Parameter name="numdoc" value="user_code"/></Client></Dial></Response>'));
}

?>
```

How can I fix it?

I'd like your help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this could be occurring because a single incoming voice call will trigger both of your $estd if statements.

According to Twilio documentation (https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/connection#status), an incoming call will first have the status pending, and then the status open. If your statuscallbackURL is set for when the status changes, you may be calling your record-keeping code more than once. Depending on how you have your SQL you may be inserting new records each time.

The way to prevent the double record is to save the resource SID for the call in your database and `insert on duplicate key` or `update` to prevent creating new records.

---

Alternatively, if the code snippet you are displaying is from record.php, when you make your outbound call using Twiml, you use a callbackURL to call record.php -- at which time you may be creating a new record in your database (as this call will have it's own unique SID). If you want to attach it to the current record, then you will need to create a different callbackURL for those outbound dials made from this script.

(But it is difficult from the details you have provided to know what code is being called when).